# How to prevent an instance of a class from being created when the condition is true. C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have the class Pos:

```
public class Pos
{
    int x;
    int y;
    public int X
    {
        get
        {
            return x;
        }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                if (value == 3)
                {
                    x = value;                                               
                }                    
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }
        }
    }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public Pos(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

I have an instance created, with X = 0. That is, as far as I understand, in the case of value = 3 -> x = 0 and in the constructor X = 0, then create an instance of the class.
How do I prevent an instance of a class from being created when the x property setter fails?
I will create a List that should not contain "wrong" objects.

Comment: I suspect that you are misunderstanding something about the sequence of operations that occurs when you create an instance of a reference type via `new`. First the instance is allocated and its fields are initialized to their default values; zero in this case. Second, the constructor is executed. Third, if the constructor throws then the `new` operation throws and, unless you've saved the reference away somewhere, it becomes garbage. If the constructor does not throw then the reference is produced by the `new` expression.

Comment: I cannot figure out what this code is supposed to do, or what the question is asking. Can you clarify it? Why would you have a setter that only allows one value to be set? If the property is not intended to be changed to any value other than 3, then why is there a setter at all? What do you mean "prevent an instance of the class being created when the setter fails?" If there is a setter running then it has to be running on an already-created instance.

Comment: I also do not understand what the `try-catch` is intended to do. The code inside the try cannot throw, and therefore the catch is useless.  Did you intend that to be an `if-else` rather than a `try-catch`?  I really am having a lot of difficulty understanding what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Also, your question asks how you prevent something when a condition is true, but it looks from the code like you are trying to prevent something when a condition is false, maybe?  Can you reconcile the question in the title with the code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's good for me. If you're interested, my goal was to block the instantiation of the class if the value != 3. I realized that my path was wrong.

Comment: If the property only has one possible value then do not provide the developer the ability to set it at all!

Comment: @EricLippert: "The code inside the try cannot throw, and therefore the catch is useless". Well, a ThreadAbortException can always be thrown, though an edge case.

Comment: @LucaCremonesi: Sure, but there is no point in catching a thread abort exception; you can't do anything helpful when one happens. The supposition of a thread abort is that the owner of the thread is unable to control it and it must be shut down as soon as possible to prevent further damage. Catching a thread abort exception is like hearing a fire alarm and deciding to first sweep up around the place before you evacuate so that it is clean when it burns down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am having a lot of difficulty understanding what this code is supposed to do and how the question relates to it, but I think maybe you are asking "how do I validate the correctness of the arguments to property setters?"

Follow this pattern:

```
// Class names should be words, not abbrvtns like "Pos"
public class Position
{
  private int x;
  private bool IsValidX(int possibleX)
  {
    // Here return true if possibleX is valid, false otherwise
  }
  public int X 
  { 
    get { return this.x; } 
    set 
    {
      if (!IsValidX(value))
        throw new ArgumentException("explanation here", "value");
      this.x = value;
    }
  }
  // Now do the same thing for Y.
  public Position(int x, int y)
  {
    if (!IsValidX(x)) 
      throw new ArgumentException("explanation here", "x");
    if (!IsValidY(y))
      throw new ArgumentException("explanation here", "y");
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

Notice that we want to throw different argument exceptions because the argument names are different in each case.